# Does the Linux kernel project use some build automation software to create their makefile?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, autotools, auto-build

Does [the Linux Kernel Project](https://github.com/torvalds/linux)  use [any build automation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software#Build_script_generation_tools) such as [autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System) to generate [their makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile)?

Do they create the makefile manually? By browsing their project Github webpage, it seems to me so, or I am missing something. But given the complexity of the project, isn't using some build automation software more convenient?

Do they use some tools to manage the complexity of their makefile?

Comment: It is managed/updated manually.

Comment: It is only top-level (and several others) makefiles have a complex structure. Makefiles in subdirectories have a well-defined format and very easy readable, so they needn't to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

The Makefiles are managed manually, but most of the complexity is confined to a few common Makefiles. See the [kbuild makefile documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) for details on the Makefiles used by kbuild.

Configuration of the kernel is rather complex, as many drivers or features depend on the presence of others. The source tree includes KConfig files and several utilities for creating a valid kernel build configuration eithe interactively or from text files. See the [kbuild documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/00-INDEX) for more details.